# How to select data with the oldest time per key in RDD?

Tags: python, pyspark, rdd

I have a RDD with two variables `ID` and `time`. The `time` is in `datetime.datetime` format. Here is a head scan of the RDD data:

```
 [[41186, datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 1, 20, 48, 5, 630000)],
 [32036, datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 2, 0, 25, 41, 950000)],
 [41186, datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 2, 0, 31, 29, 380000)],
 [40479, datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 2, 0, 39, 6, 800000)],
 [4598, datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 2, 1, 48, 47, 430000)]]
```

One `ID` will appear multiple times in the data file with different date time, and I only want to select each `ID` with the furthest time.

For example, in the sample data above, I only need to select:

```
 [[41186, datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 1, 20, 48, 5, 630000)],
 [32036, datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 2, 0, 25, 41, 950000)],
 [40479, datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 2, 0, 39, 6, 800000)],
 [4598, datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 2, 1, 48, 47, 430000)]]
```

How can I write a query to get this output? Thank you.

Comment: What does "furthest" time mean? The oldest time? Have you tried `groupby` with `min`?

Comment: Yes, the oldest time. Since I am new to Spark I am not familiar with the queries. Could you please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupByKey` and apply `min`:

```
print(rdd.groupByKey().mapValues(min).collect())
#[(41186, datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 1, 20, 48, 5, 630000)),
# (32036, datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 2, 0, 25, 41, 950000)),
# (4598, datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 2, 1, 48, 47, 430000)),
# (40479, datetime.datetime(2014, 3, 2, 0, 39, 6, 800000))]
```